# Suppose that $b\ge f(x) \ge a$ for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$ with $x \neq c$, and suppose $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$. Prove $b \ge L \ge a$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, real-numbers

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. Suppose that $b\ge f(x) \ge a$ for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$ with $x \neq c$, and suppose $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$. Prove $b \ge L \ge a$.

How do I go about tackling this problem. If I show by contradiction that $L > b$ is false and $L < a$ is false, then $L\in(a,b)$ and therefore would $L$ not be greater or equal to $a$ and less then or equal to $b$?

Side question for result: if $x=5$ can we say $x \ge 4$ since $x$ is greater and satisfies the "greater or equal" truth value? Hence, $L$ can be greater or equal to $a$ and less than or equal to $b$?

Comment: Limits preserve inequalities but weaken them in the process sometimes in an interesting manner.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the contrary. Say $L>b$. By definition of the limit, we know that $f(x)$ should be able to get arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x\to c$. But we also know that $f(x)\leq b$ for all $x\neq c$. Can you find an interval of some radius centered on $L$ that $f(x)$ cannot reach? The same argument will show why you cannot have $L<a$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I meant $L=d$. Will change that shortly.

Comment: Would the interval centered around L just be (b,2L-b) since f cannot reach b hence L cannot be greater than b?

Comment: When I say "an interval centered around $L$, I mean an interval of the form $(L-r,L+r)$. Can you find a value of $r$ such that $f(x)$ will not enter the interval?

Comment: So r=L-b so that I get the interval (b,2L-b)

Comment: That interval does work. Can you see why $f(x)$ will not enter that interval?

Comment: Yes I can, based off of our initial assumptions it's clear that f(x) has to be less than or equal to b hence it cannot enter the interval. Thank you!